# Clicking on an image to increase size

Tags: jquery

I am looking out for plugins that can display a larger image when the user clicks on it. I am aware of lightbox. Any others to compare?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63454/what-is-the-single-best-javascript-lightbox-script-currently-available

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/) and [this](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/)

Answer (score 1):

Jquery:

```
    $(function(){
        $("img").click(function(){
            str = "<img src='"+$(this).attr('src')+"' />";
            $("#img_div").html(str).fadeIn(1000);
        })
        $("#img_div").click(function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(1000);
        })
    })
```

Css:

```
#img_div{
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="img_div"></div>
<img src="Backgrounds.png" width="100px">
```

Answer (score 0):

with jquery you can try thickbox and colorbox.